# ClosedXML - Get conditional formatting Style Applied

Tags: vba, excel-formula, openxml, epplus, closedxml

I am working on manipulation Excel, in order to convert it to HTML, and I am using ClosedXML/EP plus.

**The issue here**:

I can't identify for a cell if conditional formatting has been applied or not.
When I am doing `ws.Cell(address).Style.Fill.BackgroundColor`, I am getting the default Background Color of the cell even if the conditional formatting is applied.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: you might wanna tag `vba`. `excel-formula` is all about worksheet-functions, not vba.

Comment: Thanks, will do it now

Comment: Hey, I'm dealing with the same thing, have you found a solution please? I would need to get access to Cell.DisplayFormat that is in VBA and Microsoft.Office.Excel.InterOp, but I don't know if it's possible in ClosedXML.